# Makefile error in linking static libraries

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to link my own static library into my main program.  My include headers and libraries are in the same path. g++ is able to link the main headers just fine, but its unable to find my library (ipc.a).  Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Error I'm getting when I run make is :

```
# make
g++ -o esim esim.o -L /home/vint/HobbyProjects/esim/src/LIB/PLAT -lipc -Wall -g  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lipc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Makefile is given below

```
INC_DIR = /home/vint/HobbyProjects/esim/src/LIB/PLAT
LIB_DIR = /home/vint/HobbyProjects/esim/src/LIB/PLAT
INCLUDES = -I $(INC_DIR)/

LIBS = -L$(LIB_DIR)/
LIBA = -lipc

CC = g++
DEBUG = -g
LFLAGS = -Wall $(DEBUG)
CFLAGS = -Wall -c

SOURCES = esim.cpp \

HEADERS = esim.h

OBJ = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

EXE = esim

all: esim

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) $(INCLUDES) $(LIBA) -o $(EXE) 

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $< -o $@

tar:
    tar -czf $(EXE).tar.gz $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS) Makefile

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)
    rm -f $(EXE)
```

Comment: You're not getting that when you run this makefile. This makefile would produce `-o esim` on the *end* of the final command line, the output you cited has it at the beginning. Make sure all our productions start with a tab-char.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Tried that still getting the same error, for some reason, the lib file is not being detected.

Comment: You miss the point @WhozCraig is making; the makefile you show us and the error message you show us *don't match*. If you don't show us what you're really doing, it's hard for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't add `-L/home/vint/HobbyProjects/esim/src/LIB/PLAT` option when compiling by the makefile.

Change:

```
$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) $(INCLUDES) $(LIBA) -o $(EXE)
```

Into:

```
$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) $(INCLUDES) $(LIBA) $(LIBS) -o $(EXE)
```

Comment: Changed it as above, still the same error:      `make
g++ esim.o -I /home/vint/HobbyProjects/esim/src/LIB/PLAT -lipc -o esim
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lipc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Because it still doesn't add `-L/home/vint/HobbyProjects/esim/src/LIB/PLAT` option. `$(LIBS)` should add it.

Comment: Tried that too, still no luck :( `make
g++ esim.o -I /home/vint/HobbyProjects/esim/src/LIB/PLAT -L /home/vint/HobbyProjects/esim/src/LIB/PLAT -lipc -o esim
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lipc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [esim] Error 1`

Comment: @vinit The `$(INCLUDES)` path should not even be present on the link line. And the `/` fore-slash should not be required as the tail-char on the `$(LIBS)` macro either. Run your makefile with verbose output, and *hand-paste* the output commands into your own terminal for testing. If they don't run there, they certainly won't run in a makefile either.